# Share state between siblings in ReactJS(state not in parent)

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components: Parent, Child1 and Child2. All the state is handled in Child 2 and cannot be moved to Parent(to much work at the moment). I need to change the state by onClick from Child1.

It's about a component of a big app that's gonna be rebuild soon, but no time for that at the moment.

State of Child2:

```
state = {
        selected: 0,
        type: '',
        showRootLayer: true,
        filters: {
            amount: { default: true, defaultText: 'Tutti', defaultValue: { start: 0, end: 100 }, text: '', value: '' },
            date: {
                default: true,
                defaultText: 'Week',
                defaultValue: { start: moment().subtract(1, 'week'), end: moment().subtract(1, 'day') },
                text: '',
                value: ''
            },
        }
    };
```

By clicking on button on Child1 I need  my text field of date filter from state to become 'Day':

```
state = {
        selected: 0,
        type: '',
        showRootLayer: true,
        filters: {
            amount: { default: true, defaultText: 'Tutti', defaultValue: { start: 0, end: 100 }, text: '', value: '' },
            date: {
                default: true,
                defaultText: 'Week',
                defaultValue: { start: moment().subtract(1, 'week'), end: moment().subtract(1, 'day') },
     >>>>>>>    text: 'Day',
                value: ''
            },
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is all about [data  flowing down the component's tree](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html). So horizontal communication is anti-pattern and hard to achieve. If you can't [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) consider using `redux` to centralize your state. There is `Context API` but I'm guessing won't be helpful to you cause it also involves moving the state to a `Provider`.

Comment: That's definetley an anti pattern. But this component is being used in a few cases trough app. It was build in the whole wrong way. Unfortunatelly I need a qick solution. Overall all that component need a complete rebuild and move to redux. lateron..

Comment: Yes it does. You dont share state between siblings